# passing a variable to SQL statement in KNIME

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, parameter-passing, knime

Using KNIME, I would like to analyze data in a specific subset of columns in my database 
but without using limiting SQL queries such as

Select *
From table
Where name like 'PAIN%'

Is there a way to do this in KNIME?

Comment: have you tried limiting your data according to your distinct column value..

Comment: No,at least i don't think i did, how do i go about doing that?

Comment: Probably it is too early here, but do you want to limit the columns or the rows? Both are possible with KNIME with the Column Filter nodes and the Row Filter nodes, so in the SQL query you do not need to constrain the data.

Comment: @GáborBakos  this is exactly what i'm trying to do but to limit the rows of my data to those that only contain the words 'pain'. I am new to new to KNIME so the approach i tried might be off but i connected the database connector (which contains all the columns from my database) to the database row filter. Then i used the column, operator and value dialog options to try to filter my data to "name" "like" "pain"....but that didn't work out

Answer (score 1):

Try to find specific value within the column of choice by using:

```
Select distinct(column_name) from table;
```

You can pick from the expected result to filter your data

```
Select * from table column_name like 'result_one';
```

Assuming the column_name data type is in character.

Comment: oh thanks, i know how to do this and i am actually trying to avoid using SQL queries to limit my data, if possible in KNIME

Answer (score 1):

To filer columns use the "Column Filter" node. You can filter the columns specifically, by RegEx on the column name or by column type (int, double, etc.) To filter rows based on content, use the "Row Filter" node, and select column to test and "filter based on collection elements" using pattern matching. This can also use RegEx. For mulitple columns use multiple nodes.

Answer (score 0):

the knime did not support like for now, so I used the mysql locate or FIND_IN_SET function

SELECT id  FROM address where LOCATE($street_Arr[0]$,street) > 0

SELECT id FROM address where FIND_IN_SET($street_Arr[0]$,street) > 0

however in the same situation u might be able to use knime joins much faster.